# Upgrading Zend Framework Advise

Tags: php, zend-framework, upgrade

I am using 'MJS_Controller_PathRouter' in any ancient Zend Framework version 0.6 and PHP 5.1.6. When I run this in a newer php version e.g. 5.2.x or 5.3.x, it is throwing this error:

> Declaration of
>   MJS_Controller_Router_PathRoute::__construct()
>   must be compatible with that of
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface::__construct() in
>   /opt/ezxwebadmin-versions/ezxwebadmin_2.11.5/Library/MJS/Controller/Router/PathRoute.php
>   on line 34

I would like to remove this enhanced rewrite router and upgrade our application to use a newer Zend Framework version. Our web application doesn't use any of the classes provided by Zend and we are only utilizing the MVC architecture and rewrite functionality from Zend framework.

Now could any one advise which Zend Framework version would be best for us to upgrade to?

Comment: Its always the most recent. That are the only one, that includes every bug- and security-fixes.

Comment: If you only use the MVC parts, then the best advise I can give is to remove that part and go for something simpler and testable.

Comment: Yes. I was also thinking about going with the most recent version. But the question is on the servers where we had this web app already deployed are using PHP 5.1.6, so will I be able to upgrade the web app on those servers as well if needed without upgrading PHP 5.1.6 to 5.3.x?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is actually a PHP strict coding standards error and should be fairly easy to fix. Just open up `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface` and `MJS_Controller_Router_PathRoute` and compare the parameters for the `__construct` method. They need to be the same, so change your class to match the parameters in the interface.

Zend Framework requires PHP 5.2.4. ZF2 will require PHP 5.3+. PHP 5.1.6 is almost 5 years old so you really should be upgrading (or planning to). If you are using something like CentOS with really ancient PHP packages, you might want to consider switching to Zend Server community edition (which is free). This can be installed with Yum and will give you more recent versions of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. First thing, I fixed this `MJS_Controller_Router_PathRoute` and made sure it is compatible with the `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface`. Also agreed about upgrading PHP to 5.2.x/5.3.x from 5.1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a close look at the [Zend Framework Migration Notes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/migration.html) starting at 0.8

Then look through the [Zend Framework Download Archives](http://framework.zend.com/download/archives) and upgrade your framework version by version (follow the versions listed in the migration notes) to either get to a version that works with the PHP you have or (ideally) the latest version: 1.11.x

Comment: I checked the migration notes and they are good. Thanks for pointing me to this.